# subquery in SELECT without JOIN in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, subquery

I know Hive doesn't support this

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN table1.id in (SELECT table1.id
                                from table1,table2
                                where table1.id = table2.id and table2.company like '%My Company%')
            THEN table1.email
            ELSE regexp_replace(table1.email, substr(table1.email, 1), 'XXXX') 
       END) as  email, table1.id
FROM table1
```

Hive cannot do SELECT within SELECT (subquery in SELECT).

But let say for some restriction I cannot do JOIN after FROM clause. Is there a "creative" way to do this? I was thinking about parsing and passing a "static list" from `SELECT table1.id from table1,table2 where table1.id = table2.id and table2.company like '%My Company%'` in a separate query. But this could go up to thousands.

Comment: you could use join with a subselect ?

Answer (score 2):

if you could use a select for a join  the you could  use a left join and check for null value

```
SELECT case when t1.id is null 
               then regexp_replace(table1.email, substr(table1.email, 1), 'XXXX') 
               else table1.email 
        end
       , table1.id 
    FROM table1 
    left join (
        SELECT table1.id 
        from table1,table2 
        where table1.id = table2.id 
        and table2.company like '%My Company%'
      ) t on  table1.id = t.id
```

Comment: I know this will work but the restriction unfortunately is that I cannot do a JOIN at all. The only thing I can do is changing anything in SELECT projection list. I know Postgres can let you do nested SELECT but Hive isn't the case :(

Comment: .. for what i found seems that the join are supported https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins   and join on subquery too